# change website content dynamically when mysql data base change

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a form like this in index.php file.

```
<form >
    <input type="text" id="fname" >
    <input type="text"  id="lanme" >
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

I receive two input from user.when user click on send button a jquery function called and send fname and lname to record.php file.this is jquery function.

```
$(document).ready (function() {
    $("#submit").click(fucntion(){
        $fname=$("#fname").val();
        $lanme=$("#lname").val();
        $.post("record.php") , { fname: fname , lname : lname }).done(function(data){
            alert(data);
        });
    });
});
```

and this is record.php file

```
<?php 
    $fname=$_POST['fname'];
    $lanme=$_POST['lanme'];
    $mysqli=new mysqli(host,username,password,database);
    $stmt=$mysqli->prapare("INSERT INTO info (fname , lname) VALUES (?,?))";
    $stmt->bind_param("ss",$fname , $lname);
    $stmt->execute();
 ?>
```

In index.php I print the "table" .i use this code to print table in index.php file.

```
<?php
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=HOST;dbname=DATABASENAME', $user, $password);
    $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * from info ');
    $sth->execute();
    $result = $sth->fetchAll();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}

?>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>fname</td>
    <td>lname</td>
</tr>
<?php foreach($result as $row) : ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row[0] ; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row[1] ; ?></td>
</tr> 
<?php endforeach ; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

All the above code work and I don't have any problems with it.

When user enters the value fname and lname and click on the send button, fname and lname send to the server and store in data base. If user wants to see result in table he/she must refresh page, but I want to show result on table without refreshing the page.
Otherwise when user clicks on the send button and send the data the table in the index.php dynamically change and dynamically show the result to the user.

Comment: Does `.click(fucntion()` work?

Comment: This works? => `$stmt=$mysqli->prapare`?? Unless you have a pre-made function called `prapare`, but I doubt that very much. @adib16 - It's a typo, correct?

Answer (score 1):

i Think the best way is to submit your form via Ajax and in the success-callback u attach your new row into your table e.g. with jQuery's .append(). So you dont have to reload your page at all ..

Good luck

Comment: I have a button for editing in per row in table in the index.php .if i use your solution after user send the data and I add a new row in the table with jquery when user click on the edit for new table because of the new row not added from database user can not edit the new row.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the row manually (from js). 
In my script i use the [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#template) library:

```
var template = _.template('<tr><td><%= fname %></td><td><%= lname %></td></tr>');

$.post("record.php", {fname: fname, lname : lname}).done(function() {
    $('table tr:last-child').after(template({fname: fname, lname: lname});
});
```

BTW: You should use PDO **or** mysqli not both.

Comment: I have a button for editing in per row in table in the index.php .if i use your solution after user send the data and I add a new row in the table with jquery when user click on the edit for new table because of the new row not added from database user can not edit the new row.

Answer (score 0):

You can make ajax request ( repeatedly ) from index pages and check if any new entries have been added. But it is really a overhead and effects the overall performance.

Have a look at some tools like [juggernaut](https://github.com/maccman/juggernaut) or [PeriodicalUpdater](https://github.com/RobertFischer/JQuery-PeriodicalUpdater/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make those steps:

1. Make sure your AJAX call returns the new table data (so you can display it withou reloading the page
2. After your AJAX request is done you have to change the content of your table with the data sent with AJAX
3. You should consider fixing your HTML a bit (why do you create a whole new table for each row instead of creating rows?) add some ids or class names so you can refer to them in your JS code